# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ClipboardItem'

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, blob, navigator, clipboarddata

Getting the error `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ClipboardItem'` when trying to create **ClipboardItem** for `navigator.clipboard.write()`.

`const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'image/png' : blobInput});
 await navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);`

I am using **Angular CLI: 6.0.5, Angular: 6.0.3** for building.

Comment: please provide complete ts file with the libraries you are using

Comment: "@angular/animations",
"@angular/cdk",
"@angular/common",
"@angular/compiler",
"@angular/core",
"@angular/flex-layout",
"@angular/forms",
"@angular/http",
"@angular/material",
"@angular/platform-browser",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
"@angular/router",
"@ngx-translate/core",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader",
"@types/pako",
"@types/three",
"angular2-draggable",
"core-js",
"css-element-queries",
"hammerjs",
"ng2-tooltip-directive",
"ngx-clipboard",
"ngx-color-picker",
"pako",
"rxjs",
"systemjs",
"three",
"three-orbitcontrols-ts",
"typings",
"zone.js"

Comment: The above mentioned are the libraries that I am using. Do we to add any other specific package for using **ClipboardItem**

Comment: @Kaiido
I am trying to implement [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0794oysr/2/). 

When I implemented your solution I am getting the error :
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Clipboard': Iterator getter is not callable`.

After solving it I am getting:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Clipboard': Failed to convert value to 'ClipboardItem'.`

Comment: My Code: 
`let newVariable: any;
 newVariable = window.navigator; 
 const url = canvas.toDataURL();
 const blobInput = await this.loadBlob(url);

 const dT = new DataTransfer();
 dT.items.add(new File([blobInput], 'filename', { type: 'image/png' }));
 await newVariable.clipboard.write([dT]);`